# About opening .PDF in an Android App (locally stored)

Tags: android, string, file, pdf, uri

So I have these buttons in my app that I want to open .PDF files from within the application once pressed.

I've stored my files in the /res/raw directory. Let's call them file1.PDF, file2.PDF etc.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.file1:
    Log.i(TAG, "Button one pressed");
    openPDF(Uri.parse("android:resource://test.pdf.files/raw/res/file1.PDF"));
        break;
}}
```

Above is my code for the onClick. Underneath is the code for the openPDF function.

```
public void openPDF(Uri url)
{
    File file = new File(url.toString());
    Log.i(TAG, url.toString());
    if (file.exists())
    { 
        Log.i(TAG, "File exists"); 
        Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
         try
         {
              getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent); 
         }
         catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
         {
             Log.e(TAG,"Activity not found exception");
         }
    }else{
        Log.i(TAG,"404: File not found!");
    }
}
```

My problem is as follows, I can never get past the if (file.exists()) check. I've tried making the File file take both Uri, URI and String, I have also tried more or less every variation of the filepath, like "res/raw/file1.PDF", "raw/file.PDF", "test.pdf.files/raw/res/file1.PDF". But in any of these cases I just can't find the file I want to open, can anyone see why this won't work?

I have been trying to fix this for hours and hours and I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can never get past the if (file.exists()) check

Of course. Your `Uri` does not point to a file. Your `Uri` points to a resource. Resources are not files. Files are not resources.

You can try `startActivity()` with an `Intent` that uses your resource `Uri`. If you find that PDF viewers refuse to work with that `Uri`, you will need to *copy* the resource to a local world-readable file (e.g., on external storage) and use that copy with `Uri.fromFile()` to launch your PDF viewer.

Comment: Hmm, I also now tried a whole new method. Instead of sending with the uri I simply send an int from 1-4. And inside the openPDF method I put a switch that says:
    switch (fileNumber) {
    case 1:
        File file = new File ("android:resource://test.file.pdf/res/raw/file1.PDF");
        break;
    ....
    }

Does this not work because of the same reason as the first one? Because I am still unable to find my files.

Comment: @TomErikHøvring: Please re-read my answer. **RESOURCES ARE NOT FILES**.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have misunderstood. I thought by removing the Uri middle-part i could open a file directly.

Comment: @TomErikHøvring: I can only say "resources are not files" so many times. You cannot use `File` objects on `android.resource` `Uri` values. That is because resources are not files. Delete your `File` object and `exists()` check, as they are completely useless -- if the resources are not there, then the *application* is not there, and your *code* is not there. If your code exists, so do the resources.